# Verification of substitution of variable in a complex polynomial equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

**I am writing as follows:**

The third-order polynomial of a complex variable $x,m,a,b \in \Bbb C$ is written as,

$m = ax + b{\left| x \right|^2}x$

Where, ${\left| x \right|^2} = x{x^*}$ represent norm 2 square of $x$, and $x^*$ is the conjugate of $x$.

Let, $x = cy + d{\left| y \right|^2}y$; where $c,d,y \in \Bbb C$.

Therefore,

$m = a\left( {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right) + b{\left| {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right|^2}\left( {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right)$

Now, my complicacy is to expand ${\left| {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right|^2}$.

\begin{align}
{\left| {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right|^2} &= \left( {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right){\left( {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right)^*}\\
 &= \left( {cy + d{{\left| y \right|}^2}y} \right)\left( {c^*y^* + d^*{{\left| y \right|}^2}y^*} \right)\\
 &= {\left| c \right|^2}{\left| y \right|^2} + cd^*{\left| y \right|^4} + dc^*{\left| y \right|^4} + {\left| d \right|^2}{\left| y \right|^6}
\end{align}

Am I on the right track? Or did I do any mistake?

Any suggestions will help. Thanks.

Comment: This looks good so far. Note that $cd^*+c^*d=2Re(cd^*)$, so that the last equation has all coefficients real. But what exactly do you hope to achieve using that parametrization? Does this not just make the given equation more complicated?

Comment: I was trying to isolate the real part and imaginary part after substitution to see how the real part and imaginary part behave if I change $y$.